# Finding Cubic Spline interpolation coefficients for PIV data

Tags: matlab, interpolation

LINK: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1li0D33Ngh8ZKL59rRZwqLD2q86aHRzHs/view?usp=sharing

Below code is "CUBIC SPLINE INTERPOLATION". can you help me see how the code is working. I dont understand anything about this.

Context: The code first asks for PIV data it then converts the images into matrix splits those matrix in 12 parts performs svd (POD) on those images generates low order images to reduce computational time performs cubic spline interpolation on those low order images and then combines those images to produce 7 intermediate interpolated images in between 2 consecutive images also the pixel it takes of images is 900x600. Image format is Bmp.

If you want the whole code i have mentioned a google drive link below for a pdf file

found the coefficient of the cubic spline interpolation

for z = 1:7

for i = 1:k

```
c1 = R2(i,z);
c2 = (9*R2(i,z+1) - 8*R2(i,z) - R2(i,z+3))/1.5;
c3 = (R2(i,z+2) - 2*R2(i,z+1) + R2(i,z))/0.125;
c4 = (R2(i,z+3) - 3*R2(i,z+2) + 3*R2(i,z+1) - R2(i,z))/(0.09375);

t1 = 0.03125;
t2 = 0.0625;
t3 = 0.09375;
t4 = 0.125;
t5 = 0.15625;
t6 = 0.1875;
t7 = 0.21875;

R3(i,((Z-1)*8)+1) = R2(i,z);
R3(i,((Z-1)*8)+2) = c1 + c2*t7 + c3*(t7^2) + c4*(t7^3);

R3(i,((Z-1)*8)+3) = c1 + c2*t6 + c3*(t6^2) + c4*(t6^3);

R3(i,((Z-1)*8)+4) = c1 + c2*t3 + c3*(t3^2) + c4*(t3^3);
R3(i,((Z-1)*8)+5) = c1 + c2*t4 + c3*(t4^2) + c4*(t4^3);

R3(i,((Z-1)*8)+6) = c1 + c2*t5 + c3*(t5^2) + c4*(t5^3);

R3(i,((Z-1)*8)+7) = c1 + c2*t6 + c3*(t6^2) + c4*(t6^3);
R3(i,((Z-1)*8)+8) = c1 + c2*t7 + c3*(t7^2) + c4*(t7^3);
```

end

end

for z = 8:9

for i = i:k

```
c1 = V(iz+1);
c2 = (9*V(i,z) - 8*V(i,z+1) - V(i,z-2))/1.5;
c3 = (V(i,z-1) - 2*V(i,z) + V(i,z+1))/0.125;
c4 = (V(i,z-2) - 3*V(i,z-1) + 3*V(i,z) - V(i,z+1))/(0.9375);

t1 = 0.03125;
t2 = 0.0625;
t3 = 0.09375;
t4 = 0.125;
t5 = 0.15625;
t6 = 0.1875;
t7 = 0.21875;

R3(i,((z-1)*8)+1) = R2(i,z);
R3(i,((z-1)*8)+2) = c1 + c2*t7 + c3*(t7^2) + c4*(t7^3);

R3(i,((z-1)*8)+3) = c1 + c2*t6 + c3*(t6^2) + c4*(t6^3);

R3(i,((z-1)*8)+4) = c1 + c2*t5 + c3*(t5^2) + c4*(t5^3);
R3(i,((z-1)*8)+5) = c1 + c2*t4 + c3*(t4^2) + c4*(t4^3);

R3(i,((z-1)*8)+6) = c1 + c2*t3 + c3*(t3^2) + c4*(t3^3);

R3(i,((z-1)*8)+7) = c1 + c2*t2 + c3*(t2^2) + c4*(t2^3);
R3(i,((z-1)*8)+8) = c1 + c2*t1 + c3*(t1^2) + c4*(t1^3);
```

end

end

Comment: Update: The writing of the code is similar to Horner's method